# No implicit conversion of symbol into integer while rendering JSON from nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I am new to rails API. I am getting "TypeError No implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" in rails server console for the following syntax.

```
def show
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
render json: @product.to_json(:include => 
  { :items => 
    { :only => 
      [:id, 
        :description, 
        :item_name, 
        :item_code, 
        :display_tag, 
        :price,
       {:include => 
        :item_images [:id, 
        :image_url]
      }
      ]
    }
  }
)
end
```

It should show the array of item_images as well for items while requesting the URL(e.g http://localhost:4000/products/1) my JSON is like this:

```
{
"id": 1,
"product_name": "Foundation",
"description": "test",
"image_file_name": "text.jpg",
"image_content_type": "image/jpeg",
"image_file_size": 341279,
"image_updated_at": "2018-10-24T09:28:49.000Z",
"image_url": "http://localhost:3000/system/products/1/original/text.jpg",
"created_at": "2018-08-28T14:50:29.000Z",
"updated_at": "2018-10-24T09:28:50.000Z",
"items": [
    {
        "id": 6,
        "item_name": "LOTUS WHITE GLOW COMPAC POWDER",
        "item_code": "SF264",
        "display_tag": "New",
        "description": "SKIN WHITENING AND BRIGHTENING NOURISHING\r\nSUITABLE FOR ALL SKIN TYPES\r\nULTRA-FINE SILTY FORMULA\r\nSILKY SMOOTH AND DELICATE TEXTURE\r\nCONTAINS NATURAL PLANT INGREDIENTS CAN BLOCK THE INSIDE DARK",
        "price": "1250.0"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "item_name": "Test",
        "item_code": "100",
        "display_tag": "New",
        "description": "lorem ipsum",
        "price": "200.0"
    }
]}
```

Any help?

Comment: I would really consider using ActiveModel::Serializers, fast_jsonapi or jBuilder. Inlining complex JSON structures in your controller is not ideal.

Comment: Your URL `http://localhost:4000/products/1` is of no help and may be misleading for newcomers. If the result of that call is your JSON then just erase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at:

```
{:include => :item_images [:id, :image_url]}
```

`:item_images [:id,` isn't right. You probably mean something like:

```
{:include => :item_images => {:only => [:id, :image_url]}}
```

Also that include is also in the wrong spot I believe. :include should be another key like :only is in that hash (right now :include is in the :only array). So this should work:

```
def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  render json: @product.to_json(:include => 
    { :items => 
      { :only => 
        [:id, 
          :description, 
          :item_name, 
          :item_code, 
          :display_tag, 
          :price
        ],
        :include => 
        {
          :item_images => {:only => [:id, :image_url]}
        }
      }
    }
  )
end
```

Comment: Did this question solved your problem [@Sudeep Ghimiray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7783163/sudeep-ghimiray)?

Comment: It solved the "TypeError No implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" issue but still, it doesn't fetch item_images.

Comment: @SudeepGhimiray I updated the answer now with another fix.

Comment: @Nathan Kontny Thanks